# Can a Laplace eigenfunction have a level set with a cusp like singularity?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a precompact open subset of ${\mathbb R}^2$ with piecewise 
 smooth boundary. Let $u$ be an eigenfunction of the Laplacian on $\Omega$ with either Dirichlet or Neumann conditions on $\partial \Omega$.  Is it possible that some 
level set of $u$ has a `cusp'?  By cusp, I mean a critical point $z$ of $u$ such that the level sets of $u$ topologically foliate a neighborhood of $z$.

The prototypical example of a cusp is the critical point $(0,0)$ of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3$. A Mathematica generated sketch of the topological foliation is provided here:

[image]

S. Y. Cheng observed many years ago that if a critical point lies on the  zero level set of a planar eigenfunction, then near the critical point, the zero level set is akin to that of a harmonic polynomial. It follows  that the
answer to the question is `no' if restricted to critical points that lie in the zero level set.

Comment: One way to try for a counterexample is to choose a region with an eigenvalue of large enough multiplicity that one might expect *some* eigenfunction to have a level set with the desired singularity.

Comment: Thanks Noam. We've been looking at the square and its high dimensional eigenspaces, but nothing came up yet.

Comment: The square was my first thought, but then I noticed you required smooth boundary.  Is piecewise smooth good enough?

Comment: @Noam. My apologies. I clumsily intended the word `say' to indicate the possibility of piecewise smooth. I will edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question has been answered affirmatively by Olti Myrtaj and Kelly Chen as part of a Research Experiences for Undergraduates project. See [here](https://math.indiana.edu/undergraduate/reu-summer-research-program/past-reu/2019/REU-2019-Book-small.pdf)